# Domain redirection or domain mapping?

Tags: dns, subdomain, a-records

I have a domain `aaa.com`
I have a hosting with another domain `bbb.com`

When user enter at aaa.com I need to show him the site that located at `subdomain.bbb.com`

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to display aaa.com in the address bar? Then create a CNAME record aaa.com pointing to subdomain.bbb.com in your DNS settings for aaa.com. Otherwise, create an URL redirect record similarly.